# Having a Python package install itself under a different name

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, setuptools

I'm developing a package called `garlicsim`. ([Website](http://garlicsim.org).) The package is intended for Python 2.X, but I am also offerring Python 3 support on a different fork called `garlicsim_py3`.(1)

So both of these packages live side by side on PyPI, and Python 3 users install `garlicsim_py3`, and Python 2 users install `garlicsim`.

The problem is: When third party modules want to use garlicsim, they should have one package name to refer to, not two. Sure, they can do something like this:

```
try:
    import garlicsim
except ImportError:
    import garlicsim_py3 as garlicsim
```

But I would prefer not to make the developers of these modules do this.

Is there a way that `garlicsim_py3` will install itself under the alias `garlicsim`? What I want is for a Python 3 user to be able to `import garlicsim` and refer to the module all the time as `garlicsim`, but that it will really be `garlicsim_py3`.

I know that the [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) project does something like this: They make it so you can import `setuptools` and it will be redirected into their code. I have no idea how they do it.

Any ideas?

---

(1) I've reached the decision to support Python 3 on a fork instead of in the same code base; It's important for me that the code base will be clean, and I would really not want to introduce compatibilty hacks.

Comment: I am using this exact same approach with pyparsing, and look forward to seeing what responses you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I decided not to do it, and just have the two projects have the same package name even though they have a different PyPI name.